# How to make a loading screen whilst I save my image to SD card

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gallery, saving-data

I want to know if its possible to have some sort of loading screen whilst I am saving my image to the phone. At the moment as soon as I click the Save button, it takes a while to save the image and the phone freezes up. Is this the normal process?

I have looked at some splash screens tutorials but I don't think that is what I am looking for.

** **EDIT** **

I'm new to this so I've been trying to understand how AsynxTask and Progress Dialog works. Below is what I have done so far. And this class is called whenever the button to save the image is saved.The problem is that I don't get the progress dialog coming up and also it would not save.

```
public class UITask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

private ProgressDialog p;
private File destination;
private String filename;
private Bitmap encodedBitmap;
private Context context;

public UITask(File destination,String filename,Bitmap encodedBitmap,Context context){

    this.destination = destination;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.encodedBitmap = encodedBitmap;
    this.context = context;
    this.p = new ProgressDialog(context);


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    p.setMessage("Saving image to SD Card");
    p.setIndeterminate(false);
    p.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    p.setCancelable(false);
    p.show();

}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {



    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        encodedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);


        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
    super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
    p.dismiss();
    if(aBoolean)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Download complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Failed to save image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Correction**

I have figured it out why its not saving. To do this I just simply changed return **true** in the doInBackground() function which then executes the onPostExecute() function.

Comment: Set an image, save your data in a background thread or AsyncTask, and when that is done use the onPostExecute() or a mechanism such as runOnUiThread() to set the image to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are writing your data on the ui thread. What you want to do is create an AsyncTask (example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). What you'll want to do is open a progress dialog (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) and then write the data to the sdcard in doInBackground method, in doInBackground you call publishProgress which will call onProgressUpdate which is where you'd update you progress dialog to show that write percentage complete.

Comment: Thanks for showing me some tutorials on it. I have editted my post with some code that I have written but i still don't quite fully understand.